# how to trigger a job manually from hangfire dashboard

Tags: .net-core, dashboard, hangfire

I use hangfire on a .net core project, (vs:1.7.34)
I want to trigger recurring job from the hangfire dashboard UI, There was a button before was showing "Trigger Now" but not showing trigger button now, maybe after I upgrade the hangfire version I guess. How to enable it and trigger jobs from dashboard manually?

settings like tihs;

```
public static class HangfireHelper
{
    public static void AddHangfire(IServiceCollection services, string connectionString, string recurrence)
    {
        services.AddHangfire(x =>
        {
            x.UsePostgreSqlStorage(connectionString);
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<MyClass>(e => e.MyMethodToExecute(), recurrence);
        });

        services.AddHangfireServer(ops =>
        {
            ops.ServerName = "my job server";
            ops.WorkerCount = 10;                
            ops.Queues = new string[] { "general" };
            ops.SchedulePollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            ops.CancellationCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible you implemented access restrictions in your hangfire settings that prevents you from executions. ReadOnly would do that